# '_RSAPublicKey' object has no attribute 'sign' in python

Tags: python

I am using JWT tokens, I have created public and private JWT tokens using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

Two (public and private) files are successfully created on the given path.

When I try to access it from the python script like this:

**Reading file**

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, '../../instance/jwt-key.pub')
with open(file_path, 'r') as keys:
    jwt_keys = keys.read()
```

**main.py**

```
def loginM(email, password):
     user_reg = Registration.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
     if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user_reg.password, password):
         identity = {'first_name': user_reg.first_name, 'exp': time.time() + 1440}
         token = jwt.encode(identity, jwt_keys, algorithm='RS256').decode('utf-8')
         print(token)
         return dict(token=token)
     else:
         return dict(Unsucessful="Invalid username and password")
```

When I try to print the token, I am getting an error like this.

> '_RSAPublicKey' object has no attribute 'sign'

When I print the jwt_keys directly it is printing the token.

If the do the same process like this in the console it is working perfectly.

**CMD Code.**

Here the jwt public and private files are in the same folder:

```
import jwt
payload = {'mae':'sao'}
key = open('jwt_key').read()
token = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm='RS256').decode('utf-8')
```

When I print token I am able to see the token, but when I do it from the python file I am getting an error which is mentioned as title, how can I solve this.

Comment: You're trying to access to file using relative path from script, which won't work if you're executing it from different path.

Comment: @Olvin Roght how can I solve that problem

Comment: Try to not use relative path.

Comment: @OlvinRoght In this scenario, how to use absolute path

Comment: `file_path = '/full/path/to/your/file'`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the question is still valid but according to the [jwt documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

method `jwt.encode()` takes private key as a key parameter:

```
encoded = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, private_key, algorithm='RS256')
```

however, you are reading the public one from file:

```
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, '../../instance/jwt-key.pub')
```

The second issue is that the private key should be byte type:

```
private_key = b'-----BEGIN PRIVAT...'
```

so you should open file in binary format with `b` flag:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as keys:
```